# Rounding a number using non standard rules

Tags: c#, .net, decimal

Consider the following C# code:

```
Decimal number = new decimal(8.0549);
Decimal rounded = Math.Round(number, 2);
Console.WriteLine("rounded value: {0}", rounded);
```

will produce the output: 8.05

Math.Round's algoritm only checks the next digit beyond the decimals number taken as parameter.
I need a algoritm that checks all the decimals chain. In this case, 9 should rounds 4 to 5 which in turn will rounds 5 to 6, producing the final result 8.06

More exemples:
8.0545 -> 8.06
8.0544 -> 8.05

There's some built-in method that can help me?
Thanks.

Comment: I assume you are aware that the rounding you are proposing is not mathematically correct? I.e. 8.0545 is closer to 8.05 than it is to 8.06, so rounding to 8.06 is not correct rounding.

Comment: Just curious (since what you are looking for is not rounding).... why? ;)

Comment: Yes, i'm aware that this is not mathematically correct. That's because i called it "non standard". But it continues to be a rounding, not? :) I don't agree with this rule too. But is superior orders..

Comment: @Zé Carlos: No, this is not really rounding. Rounding is about getting to the closest number using fewer digits, you are actually getting to a different number which is close, but not the correct rounded value.

Comment: Isn't your superior trying to avoid so called banker's rounding by some chance?

Comment: I might suggest telling your superior that this isn't possible.

Comment: BTW there are literals of the decimal type in the language. I suggest using `decimal number = 8.0549m` instead of converting double literal to decimal. Converting from double can cause some unintuitive rounding behaviour too. Maybe that's the cause for the request

Comment: The (perhaps more) interesting question here is to come up with a demonstration that applying the specified procedure can sometimes produce 'obviously' wrong results (for suitable values of 'obviously', of course)

Comment: @AkashM - there is an example of this in the question - rounding 8.0549 to 8.06 is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; you'll need to write it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect that if there were a built in method to do this, it would have already been reported as a bug ;)

That being said - you could create a method that takes your decimal, along with the max and min number of places to round in reverse from, and in a loop crush it down to the desired places - i.e. something like this:

```
    private static double NotQuiteRounding(double numToRound, int maxPlaces, int minPlaces) 
{ 
    int i = maxPlaces;
    do
    { 
        numToRound = Math.Round(numToRound,i); 
        i = i - 1;
    } 
    while (i >= minPlaces);

    return numToRound; 
}
```

And call it like this:

```
    Console.WriteLine(NotQuiteRounding(8.0545,10,2));
    Console.WriteLine(NotQuiteRounding(8.0544,10,2));
```

Comment: Just don't do this, otherwise at the end of the routine, things will be unleashed and children will be eaten.

Comment: .. indeed ... but to come up with this on Halloween is highly appropriate though:-)

Comment: Shouldn't `i` decrease instead of increasing?